# How to achieve this tone?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, guitar-effects, tone

I have been going crazy for months trying to replicate this tone. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My setup: 
Epiphone Les Paul custom top pro
Marshall dsl40cr
Seymour Duncan palladium (distortion)
Eventide timefactor (delay)
Hall of Fame 2 (reverb)

Comment: What about your current tone doesn't sound like the tone you are trying to get? He might have a slight phaser on there.

Comment: Why don't you post a comment on the guy's YouTube channel and ask him?

Answer (score 1):

I hear a Peavey Vypyr VIP amplifier there, with the Fender Twin modeling selected, and the distortion, delay, and a huge wall of reverb engaged.

$200 American, and that amp can be yours.

Answer (score -1):

I like that tone as well.

Looking at the YouTube comments for the video (Ryan Leslie) I see he states he used a Digitech RP1000 Guitar Multi-Effects Processor.

I think you'd get real good feedback if you contacted many of the folks who reviewed the RP1000, like this guy,

, and ask them for insight on the settings.

Maybe they'd like that video too and recreate that sound for you and be able to share it ... I don't know if the RP1000 lets users publish sound setup files.

The RP1000 are listed for $399 on Digitech but I see they've been as low as $155 used on Reverb so for $200-ish you could easily try it and resell it should it not fit the bill.

https://digitech.com/en/products/rp1000